# Duplicate Packages Error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, duplicate

When I run sudo apt-get update, the following results occur :

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry google'sIP/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry google'sIP/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

The solution Ubuntu provides is " run apt-get update to correct these problems" , but that only produces the duplicate error.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu Software Center select the menu entry Edit -> Software Sources and

under the Other Software tab try to remove the duplicate entries.